# Python Self Replicating Class

Tags: python, class, object, initialization, metaclass

I am messing about with having a class recreate itself. I am trying to get an understanding of metaclass attribute but I am still not 100% clear.

The Goal:
A Class that creates itself for some iteration and then holds its first degree of children it created (In the example below that is one object in self.children).

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, num):

        self.name = num
        self.children = []

        if num !=0:
            cls = self.__new__(self.__class__ )
            cls = self.__init__(num-1)
            self.children.append(cls)

            #Uncomment for Error
            #print cls.name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = MyClass(3)
```

This is what I am trying but trying to print self.name of the new object returns a kind AttributeError that "name" does not exist. I think its because I am not passing a dict of the attributes but I am looking for some clarifications of best practice and maybe a solution.

If I was not clear on something please let me know so I can better explain!

Comment: I admit that I don't fully understand what you're doing, but `cls = self.__init__(num-1)` doesn't look right to me. `__init__` always returns `None`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kevin __init__ in this case returned a class object.

Comment: `__init__()` returning anything other than `None` will result in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call the `__new__()` or `__init__()` methods yourself; the constructor will handle that part automagically.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.name = num
        self.children = []

        if num !=0:
            cls = self.__class__(num-1)
            self.children.append(cls)
            print cls.name
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.name = num
        self.children = []

        if num != 0:
            self.children.append(self.__class__(num - 1))

if __name__=="__main__":
    c = MyClass(3)
```